# How To Determine Whether A User Attempted A SQL Injection Attack

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I'm familiar with using `mysql_real_escape_string()` and the PHP `FILTER_SANITIZE` function to prevent sql injections.

However, I'm curious as to how I would determine within a PHP script whether or not user input was a likely sql injection attempt? That would be useful for tracking potentially malicious IPs.

Comment: First define what a "likely SQL injection attack" looks like. An attacker may simply start with, for example, `O'Connor`. If that produces an error, the attacker knows you're not escaping input. Does `O'Connor` constitute an attack?

Comment: That's what mod_security and the core rules already do.

Answer (score 6):

If the output of `mysql_real_escape_string` is different to the input, then the input contained unsafe characters.  You could infer that the user *might* have been attempting an attack, especially if the field in question is one where you'd normally expect a low number of unsafe characters (e.g. a zip code).

But it might also be because their name happened to be `Robert'); DROP TABLE Students; --`.

So in general, there is no way to do this that's even close to reliable.

Comment: Won't work. E.g. this comment naturally contains a single quote!

Comment: @Oli: I'm not disputing that :) And, due to my cunning workaround of SO's one-person-one-vote limit, you are not actually penalised by my downvote ;)

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is you cannot. Just write code that assumes that the serve is going to receive a pounding then you cannot go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very hard problem to solve, automatically detecting which SQL queries are attacks (or simple mistakes).

There are companies who make products that attempt to do this, like GreenSQL and DB Networks ADF-4200, by applying heuristic tests to see if queries look "suspicious."

But even they rely more on whitelisting the queries that your application runs. The heuristics are known to have both false positives and false negatives. And there are whole categories of queries that neither whitelisting nor heuristics can catch, like calls to stored procedures.

Someone mentioned [mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/) too, but this requires a lot of configuration, and then you're back to hand-coding rules for whitelisting your application's legitimate queries.

Just follow good practices like parameterizing and whitelisting, so that user input (or any untrusted content) is never evaluated as code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no certain way ! 
but it is possible to guess attacks ! 
simply check for most common usefull sql injection structures
for example scan this words (in case insensitive) in your inputs :

```
union
select
drop
--
;
```

if you know how to stop sql injection , you shouldn't be worried and you can run the query safely. but as I understood you want to detect injections , so i prefer you just log suspicious inputs and then decide manually ! in most cases logged queries are real injections.

Comment: The union needs to select a new leader to drop their old baggage--surely a daunting task; and we'll see how that goes...

Comment: notice that the injected query is not always right structured ! some times attacker needs to get error messages so they can easily use union and creat the error msg.

Answer (score 0):

Test for '--' and ';' strings ... maybe also OR, AND, (, etc. But you can never be 100% sure it WAS an attack.

Comment: Because these characters--in real life--are never used in English text; as was easy to show here?

Comment: This should be moved to meta where we can discuss why Thomas hasn't been auto-banned from SO for obviously trying to hack the site.

Comment: @Wooble, don't tell anyone! I'll increase your rep too!'); update UserRep set Rep = Rep * 2 where User = 'Wooble' or User = 'tomas'; --

Comment: @deceze: Strictly speaking, that semicolon is erroneous ;)

Comment: @Tomalak Then maybe it *should* be identified as an attack - on the English language. :o)

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's safer to assume that ALL user input is an attack when you write your code and make your program secure enough to mitigate the attack rather than trying to retroactively fix something that may or may not have been an attack.

Comment: Oh, I do.  But what I wanted to do was find a way to zero in on IPs in which the malicious input was unusually high, and blacklist that IP.

Comment: The problem is that there are so many types of attacks, and more are being thought of all the time (SQL injection, CLI injection, XSS, DDoS, brute force, CSRF, social engineering, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. If there are no characters to be escaped in the input string, then
   it's not an attack attempt.
2. Put the user input in the query *without* quoting.
3. Try to check the query syntax **without running it** (e.g. make mysql do it for you somehow (?)).
4. If there is no syntax error, then it was an attack attempt.

But this way you can only detect potentially successful attack attempts, not those which give parse error.

Answer (score 0):

You may search for certain keys (`union`,`delete`,`drop`, `...`) and so on. Search for `--`, `\n` (new lines) if you are sure that original query would never ever have it. Create a query that always returns some value - if with user malicious input it doesn't that may indicate an attack.

But because users tend to ALWAYS make mistakes or attack servers (number, i will write letters to check how much mess it will make...) all user inputs should be filtered before used.

Answer (score -4):

(joke deleted)

**EDIT**: You can try the following:

1. If there are no characters to be escaped in the input string, then
   it's not an attack attempt.
2. Put the user input in the query *without* quoting.
3. Try to check the query syntax **without running it** (e.g. make mysql do it for you somehow (?)).
4. If there is no syntax error, then it was an attack attempt.

But this way you can only detect potentially successful attack attempts, not those which give parse error.

Comment: -1: "parse the query without running somehow" - how would this help?

Comment: when downvoting, write what you consider wrong about my post! There's nothing false in it, I was the first who proposed the syntax method here...

Comment: @Oli - to detect whether it was an attempt of sql injection, that what the OP asked.

Comment: This will tell you no more than comparing input and output of `mysql_real_escape_string`.  And how do you propose to determine whether the resulting query string was affected or not?

Comment: Your answer contains a terrifically bad piece of advice, a joke and a vague idea that's not helping to answer the question at all. Why *shouldn't* we downvote it?

Comment: @Oli, isn't that clear? "O'Brien" wouldn't parse, however "'); drop table X --" would! Then it'd be clear what is an attack!

Comment: @Tomas: This assumes that "attack" means "successful attack"

Comment: `if there is no syntax error, then it was an attack attempt` -- So, any normal query is an attack now?

Comment: @deceze, of course, with the added condition that there some characters to be escaped in it! Ok, my fault, I wasn't formal enough, going to fix it.

Comment: So `SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'O\'Connor'` is an attack now...? :o)

Comment: @deceze, nope. The user entered "O'Connor". When you put O'Connor to the query *without* quoting, it will be syntax error.

Comment: @deceze: I updated my post to be even more clear. I'm sure you will find some counterexample, go ahead, looking forward :-)

Comment: This is much better. You should have posted it as a new answer, as it's not related to the original one in any way.